# Projector mounting location to reduce noise

Tags: home-theater, projector

With my desired screen size, the placement of my desired [projector (Optome HD141X)](http://www.optomaeurope.com/projectordetailshe.aspx?PTypeDB=Home%20Entertainment&PC=HD141X) is right above my head (approx. 1m far as the seating is elevated in the room).

I am a projector novice and thus I am not sure how much noise can the projector generate in such short proximity. The specified noise is 26dB, however, I am not sure at which distance is this measured?

So to my main question - is it worth looking at another projector, most likely short-throw, that would be mounted closer to the screen and thus further from my seating location? (3m far away for the short throw).

I quite like the projector I found and the price seems reasonable but I have no idea what to expect in terms of noise, and I would be sitting quite close..

Comment: Hey, a few years later, I'm having the same question. We'd love to hear how it turned out for you! Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Just as a frame of reference, 26dB is about the sound level of a person breathing. Typically these are measured at a distance of a meter from the source. Whether or not this will be objectionable is mainly a question of personal preference (and how much other sound sources such as your speakers mask it). My suggestion would be to pick up a computer case fan with a comparable decibel rating, put it where the projector will go and see if it would be a problem for you.

As far as increasing distance goes, it will obviously help. Sound level drops by roughly 6dB for every *doubling* of the distance, so at 2 meters it should be barely perceptible and at 4 meters you would have to try really hard to pick it out.

Bear in mind that 26dB is the *claimed* decibel rating, and the actual noise level you perceive can vary depending on frequency, vibrations in whatever it's attached to, etc.